# C# Как передать информацию с 1 Формы во 2

Tags: c#

```
    public static void PopulateListBox3(ListBox lsb, string Folder, string FileType)
    {
        DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Folder);
        FileInfo[] files = directoryInfo.GetFiles(FileType);
        FileInfo[] array = files;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            FileInfo fileInfo = array[i];
            lsb.Items.Add(fileInfo.Name);
        }
    }

    private void Svheta_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.listBox1.Items.Clear();
        PopulateListBox3(this.listBox1, "./Texts", "*.txt");
        PopulateListBox3(this.listBox1, "./Texts", "*.lua");
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Frasth G2 = new Frasth();
        Frasth f2 = (Frasth)this.Owner;
        Frasth f1 = new Frasth();
        string text = File.ReadAllText(string.Format("./Texts/{0}", this.listBox1.SelectedItem));
        f2.richTextBox1.Text = text;
    }
}
```

что делать?

Comment: Как ваш код связан с вашим же вопросом? Форма - такой же объект, как и все остальные. Как вы передаете данные между объектами других ваших классов? Вот ровно также передается между формами.

Comment: В общем это всё что передаётся с формы в форму других классов нет

Comment: после нажатия на текст в ListBox выдаёт ошибку Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

Comment: [измените вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1030601/edit) и внесите в него уточнения.

Comment: В каком месте падает-то?

Comment: Как вариант - через конструктор )

Comment: `Frasth f2 = (Frasth)this.Owner;` проверьте в отладчике что тут результат не null